# Confused in Newton's second law for rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

I'm a high school student and I am really confused about a point from rotational mechanics.
My confusion is as follows-

We are often taught that $\tau=dL/dt$ and $\tau=I\alpha$ are the same if the moment of inertia is constant about an axis, but my problem is that when I apply  $\tau=dL/dt$ to solve any problem, I can apply it to any point I want to whether it is moving, accelerated or at rest but when I use $\tau=I\alpha$ I can only apply it to certain points which lie on the body of the object that is rotating and not anywhere else.

In the image that I have attached below, I have shown that even if I choose which moment of inertia is constant, we still cannot use $\tau=I\alpha$  about that point, but we can still use $\tau=dL/dt$ about that point. Why is this happening? I would be really glad if someone could solve this problem by applying  ***τ=Iα"*** about choosing the same point that I have chosen. I think that would help me clarify my concepts about rotational mechanics problems.

[image: sorry for the handwriting]

Comment: Please describe the set up and write equation in latex

Comment: Note that $\mathbf{\tau}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{L}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is only true if one of the following is true: 1) the origin is the center of mass; 2) the origin is not accelerating; 3) $\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{r}_0$ is parallel to $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_0$.

Comment: then why i am getting the correct answer ,not only in this problem you can solve any problem if you apply τ=dL/dt about ny point whether it is acceleration of stationary ,and you always get the correct answer just like i get for every problem ,does it mean that τ=dLdt and  τ=Iα" have major differences, it is not just that if moment of inertia is constant you can use  τ=Iα ,it has some much deeper differences.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the question more properly, and I have edited my answer.

The angular momentum about a point outside the rotating body is $\vec L=I_{cm} \vec \omega + m({\vec{v}_{cm} \times \vec{x}_{cm}})$

Thus, the torque will not be $I\alpha$, I apologize for my previously incorrect answer. The torque is equal to $I\alpha$ only if the origin is moving with the same $\alpha$ about the same axis as the rotating body, and the moment of inertia is constant.

However, I have no idea why you have chosen such a convoluted way to solve this sum. Why the frame of reference at a random point outside the body, which is also accelerating?

Taking the COM as the reference, you get

$\tau = I \alpha$

$\therefore TR= mK^2 \frac aR$       $\therefore T=\frac{K^2}{R^2}ma$

$mg= ma + T$       $\therefore mg = ma + \frac{K^2}{R^2}ma$

$$\therefore a=g\frac{R^2}{R^2+K^2}$$

Comment: i mean you cannot get the right answer if you apply  τ=Iα about the same point which i have chosen in this problem,if you don't believe me ,you can try it by yourself and if you get the right answer then my confusion will also get clear

Comment: it would reallr clarify my concepts if you show me that we can solve this problem about the same point which i have chosen in this problem by applying  τ=Iα" and still get the right answer:)

Comment: I did not understand your this line "The torque is equal to Iα only if the origin is moving with the same ω about the same axis as the rotating body.". This is not even written in any book, and  by choosing such a random point I want to prove that the these two equations i.e τ=Iα and τ=dL/dt have many differences its not like that, if moment of inertia is constant w.r.t time then they are same,,, by solving this problem about the point which i have chosen you can clearly see that you cannot apply  τ=Iα  about this point however moment of inertia is constant about this point ,

Comment: What did you not understand about my statement?

Comment: from where does this statement come? this is not written anywhere, and by the way it doesn't clear my confusion, my confusion is that these two equation i.e τ=Iα and τ=dL/dt  have many many differences and if you are saying that "The torque is equal to Iα only if the origin is moving with the same ω about the same axis as the rotating body.".Then why we can even apply τ=dL/dt  here and still get the correct answer

Comment: $\tau = \frac {dL}{dt}$ can be used everywhere. When the frame of reference matches the conditions that i mentioned, then $\frac {dL}{dt} = I \alpha$ In other cases, $\frac {dL}{dt}$ has different values depending on the situations.

Comment: does it mean that these two equations have many differences ,i.e we cannot say that if moment of inertia is constant then these two are same ,,even then they are not same?

Comment: There aren't two equations, the only equation is $\tau = \frac{dL}{dt}$. You need to find the value of $\frac{dL}{dt}$ according to the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The moment of inertia is not the same if the object is taken to rotate through a different axis, you need to apply the [Steiner formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem). Remember that $I$ is a measure of the geometrical distribution of mass around the rotation axis.

Comment: for the same i mean to say that it is constant about that point and not changing, ofcourse the moment of inertia about the point which i have chosen is not the same as that of of Center of mass but it is constant whatever it is you can easily find with the help of parallel axis theorem but my confusion will get clear if could possibly show me that we can solve this problem about the point which i have chosen by applying  τ=Iα

Comment: What is that force "Ma" upwards from the mass center in your scheme?

Comment: it is the pseudo force, as our frame of reference from which we are working is itself accelerated  we must apply a pseudo force.

Comment: And I must inform you that the answer that I get for a is just its value which we get w.r.t the frame from which we are working, in order to get the correct direction also you should use a{com/p}=a{com}+a{p}, but for this problem i have already taken the acceleration of point to be the same a s that of COM so I just don't need to do this

Answer (score 0):

The formula: τ = Iα assumes that each point in the object has the same angular acceleration relative to the chosen axis (it is rotating as a rigid body).  If an object is moving past a reference point and rotating, each motion contributes to the angular momentum.

Comment: _Every_ point on a rigid body shares the same $\omega$ and $\alpha$. The difference between locations is the $I$.

Comment: yes about the point i have chosen which is moving with the same acceleration as that center of mass the angular acceleration is same only the difference is that moment of inetrtia is =I{w.r.t com}+M{R+x}^2 but its is also not changing wr.t time, so why we cannot apply τ=Iα  about the point which i have chosen in this problem to get the correct answer